# Application number and number of claims on patent US3263485 A

Tags: application

In reference to the patent: [US3263485](https://www.google.com/patents/US3263485)

what is the Application number and number of claims on patent US3263485 A?

Comment: The number of claims is obvious by simply looking at the link you provided. Is there some reason for asking this?

Answer (score 1):

A PDF of US patent 3,263,485 is available here: http://www.pat2pdf.org/patents/pat3263485.pdf . The Google Patents version is not that great.

The application number or serial number (Ser. No.) is 341,349 as shown on the second page of the patent publication.

The patent has 6 claims - 3 independent claims and 3 dependent claims.

It was filed January 30, 1964, issued August 2, 1966, and is now expired.

Answer (score 0):

The application no. is:
US19640341349 19640130
There are 6 claims.

Comment: This answer would be better if it described the method used to obtain the application number.

Comment: The Espacenet database entry for this patent shows the citations to the  two application/priority documents.